# Is there a list of routecards for Ticket to Ride: Nordic Countries?

Tags: ticket-to-ride, ticket-to-ride-nordic-countries

Is there a list of all routecards with points on the internet for nordic countries? I tried to look for it but could only find them for the normal version.

Answer (score 7):

BoardGameGeek has what you are looking for [here](https://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/41269/ticket-ride-nordic-countries-tables-ticket-values). They require an account to download files, so I've copied the relevant information below:

24  KØBENHAVN – MURMANSK
21  OSLO – HONNINGSVÅG
18  KØBENHAVN – NARVIK
18  STAVANGER – ROVANIEMI
17  BERGEN – TORNIO
17  STOCKHOLM – TROMSØ
16  BERGEN – NARVIK
14  KØBENHAVN – OULU
13  HELSINKI – KIRKENES
13  NARVIK – TALLINN
12  GÖTEBORG – OULU
12  HELSINKI – BERGEN
12  KRISTIANSAND – MO I RANA
12  NARVIK – MURMANSK
11  NORRKÖPING – BODEN
11  TROMSØ – VAASA
11  ÅLBORG – UMEÅ
10  HELSINKI – KIRUNA
10  HELSINKI – KØBENHAVN
10  OSLO – MO I RANA
10  STOCKHOLM – KAJAANI
10  TAMPERE – KRISTIANSAND
10  TURKU – TRONDHEIM
10  ÖREBRO – KUOPIO
9   OSLO – VAASA
8   BERGEN – KØBENHAVN
8   HELSINKI – ÖSTERSUND
8   OSLO – HELSINKI
8   STAVANGER – KARLSKRONA
8   STOCKHOLM – BERGEN
7   BERGEN – TRONDHEIM
7   GÖTEBORG – TURKU
7   STOCKHOLM – IMATRA
7   STOCKHOLM – UMEÅ
6   GÖTEBORG – ÅNDALSNES
6   STOCKHOLM – KØBENHAVN
6   SUNDSVALL – LAHTI
6   TAMPERE – BODEN
6   TORNIO – IMATRA
6   ÅRHUS – LILLEHAMMER
5   HELSINKI – LIEKSA
5   ÅLBORG – NORRKÖPING
4   OSLO – KØBENHAVN
4   OSLO – STAVANGER
4   OSLO – STOCKHOLM
3   TAMPERE – TALLINN